# Shall I create an ArrayBuffer every time or shall I clear a previously created one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cross-browser

I need an ArrayBuffer having the size of (65536 * 2). When you create an ArrayBuffer, it contains all zeros which is convenient.

Now, whenever I need a clean (filled with zero) ArrayBuffer, shall I create a new local instance or shall I create a global instance that I clear (by using an Uint32 view) every time I need ?

I need to use this buffer once in every 10 seconds & it should give the same performance on all major browsers. Any experience/thoughts about this ?

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer without testing it.

Go here and try it with all browsers :

<del>http://jsperf.com/arraybuffer-fill-with-0-vs-creating-a-new-one</del>

EDIT : There is a bug in the previous code, try this one :

http://jsperf.com/arraybuffer-fill-with-0-vs-creating-a-new-one-fixed

Comment: Only Firefox-PC performed better for the GlobalBuffer case, which was insignificant. Thanks...

Comment: Do you know any other tool/site to test the long term effects of this scheme ? For example, does creating a local ArrayBuffer each time cause heap fragmentation ?

Comment: The garbage collector should work fine. Have a look at the developer tools in Google Chrome, I think there is something for the memory in the profiler.

Comment: Sorry, but had to give vote down, this is no answer at all, jsperf is down and there is nothing in the answer that points in any direction. You could have copied tests here also to help others, not just rely on jsperf. Or at least copy results.